# Make a link have not clickable padding but a clickable background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of links with background images, and they all have padding which I do not want to be clickable. However, I would like to be able to click on the background images. Is it possible to enable pointer events on a background-image? I'm willing to do it through CSS or through JS.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("?????").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("a span").css({"color":"green"});
    });
});
```

I have a function that is roughly something of this nature (but a bit more complicated) in jQuery, but I would like the click to only reference the background image, so I'm not really sure what to do.

Here's a demo of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/x7bdu/7/

In this case, I'd like to be able to click on the pencil image.

I've done something similar thing jQuery, but I'd like the mouse to look as though an area cannot be clicked, and my solution does not stop the mouse from changing, which is why I'm looking for an alternate means.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: sorry, but right now I am simply questioning your use of the background image as the clickable element. Why does it have to be a background image ? Can it simply be a separate element positioned where you want it to be ?

Comment: yea it's weird, i know. i'm improving a section of an existing site by adding a drop down menu and it's already been done this way - i tried restructuring it but the formatting ended up getting completely messed up so i've been trying to leave most of the pre-existing stuff intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is all you need, but to prevent the mouse from changing, you simply need to do

```
a {
  cursor: default;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/x7bdu/11/

Comment: ah, i actually knew about that and didn't think of doing that for some reason. it doesn't technically do exactly what i'd hoped for (my guess is that what I want doesn't actually exist...), but aesthetically it works and that's good enough for me! thanks for your help!